# Get images of movies in gridview to my android app using picasso

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I am trying to get images of movies in gridview to my android app using picasso, but the app is crashing on run time.

This is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.manik.organisingmovies;
{
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

**ArrangeMovies.java**

```
    package com.example.manik.organisingmovies;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by manik on 13/4/16.
     */
    public class ArrangeMovies extends Fragment {
        private ArrayAdapter<ImageView> adapter;
        protected GridView gridView;
        protected ImageView imageview;
        String movieJsonstr = null;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.arrangemovies, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                UpdateList();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        private void UpdateList()
        {
            Arrange a=new Arrange();
            a.execute();
        }
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            UpdateList();
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater Inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootview = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            //Initialize with empty data
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_image_group, R.id.gridView, new ArrayList<ImageView>());
            gridView=(GridView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            imageview=(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.list_image_group);
            return rootview;
        }

        public class Arrange extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Uri[]> {
            protected Uri[] doInBackground(String... params) {
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                final String api_k = "01d90477383c17bfcff10ffab96f6e7f";
                try {
                    final String Base_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?";
                    final String key = "api_key";
                    Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(Base_URL).buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(key, api_k)
                            .build();
                    URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null)
                        return null;
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                        // buffer for debugging.
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                        return null;
                    }
                    movieJsonstr = buffer.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    movieJsonstr = null;
                    return null;
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (final IOException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                try{
                    Uri[] s=new Uri[1000];
                    s=getImageurl(movieJsonstr);
                    return s;
                }catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Uri[] result) {
                adapter.clear();
                    for(Uri moviestr:result)
                    {
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(moviestr).into(imageview);
                        adapter.add(imageview);
                    }
                }
            }
    private Uri[] getImageurl(String movieJsonstr) throws JSONException {
        final String movie_array="results";
        final String image_url="poster_path";
        final String movie_title="title";
        final String movie_id="id";
        final String movie_date="release_date";
        final String movie_rate="vote_average";
        JSONObject movieJson=new JSONObject(movieJsonstr);
        JSONArray moviearray=movieJson.getJSONArray(movie_array);
        Uri[] movie_images=new Uri[moviearray.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<moviearray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject movie=moviearray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject url=movie.getJSONObject(image_url);
            String link=url.getString(image_url);
            final String base_url="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
            Uri buildlink=Uri.parse(base_url).buildUpon()
                    .appendPath(link)
                    .build();
            movie_images[i]=buildlink;
        }
    return movie_images;
    }
    };
    }
```

**list_image_group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_image_group">

</ImageView>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.manik.organisingmovies.ArrangeMovies"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:numColumns="2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is error as in logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.example.manik.organisingmovies, PID: 19647

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.manik.organisingmovies/com.example.manik.organisingmovies.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
    at com.example.manik.organisingmovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
    at com.example.manik.organisingmovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:454)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2252)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
    at com.example.manik.organisingmovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Something is wrong in your `activity_main.xml` file, but it is not clear what from the stack trace.

Comment: I think you need to `extend Activity` NOT `extend AppCompatActivity`

Comment: I tried by extending Activity but still I am getting the same error.